# Compiling Fixed Form Fortran code in Visual Studio Code using gfortran not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

When I use the regular gfortran **FortranFreeForm**

[image: FreeForm]

it compiles, but when I choose the **FortranFixedForm** it doesn't work.

[image: Fortran77]

Comes back with the Error "Code language not supported or defined"

[image: Error]

But when I go into the settings.json the free form and fixed form command
set up in the executor map is the same

[image: Settings.json]

```
"FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
```

What is wrong with the setup? Why doesn't the FixedForm work?
It has the same command setup for it, so shouldn't it just run the same way?

You can compile this "helloworld" code to try this out

```
      PROGRAM main
!     The PRINT statement is like WRITE,
!     but prints to the standard output unit
         PRINT '(A)', 'Hello, world'
         STOP
      END
```

Comment: Note fixed form /= Fortran 77. Fixed form to this day is still perfectly valid Fortran 2018. And in fact your example code is at least Fortran 90

Comment: @IanBush ok but doesn't explain why its not compiling if the same compiler command is used?  Also in the ModernFortran setup when you select FortranFixedForm it comes up as Fortran77 though. So seems ModernFortran is saying it is Fortran77 style code.

Comment: @AndiAna It's a matter of convenience. The vscode ext (and the language server) does not care for Fortran 90, 2018 or 77. What matters is if it's free or fixed form. We alias Fixed Form Fortran to Fortran77, among other things, because that is the **most likely occurrence** for fixed form codes. So the default behaviour is what most users are looking for. In vscode, you can always tweak your settings if you want something else.

Answer (score 0):

The language ID tag is not `fortran_fixed-form` but `FortranFixedForm` as shown in the Command Palette dropdown. This change was introduced with v3.0.0 of Modern Fortran for VS Code.

Renaming `fortran_fixed-form` --> `FortranFixedForm` should fix your problem.